# What's the purpose of using the 'inquestion' search operator?

Tags: support, search

I was looking at some examples from the help page on searching, and came across `inquestion`. As far as I'm aware of what it does is that it takes the id of the question

```
inquestion:50691
```

And restricts the results to just question and answer's in a long form view. What's the point when you can open the question and view all comments and questions?

It would be nice to have some clarification on this.

Comment: The help center description is bit wrong, it can also be used to "search" inside answers as well, e.g. to check if certain answer has certain keyword. (So they should write "posts", and not "questions")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's no better than <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> in your browser if all the answers fit on one page. However, after 30 answers, they get paginated and don't fit on a single page anymore. I use it frequently to check [whether I need to post a new meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19478/295232), or report a bug / propose a feature request during a [product discovery](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/product-discovery).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was using it on questions with like 3 answers. didn't realize that after 20-something questions how great it would be.